# The "Page Content" is getting added below the page of app instead getting added on the Mater Page UI

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, custom-masterpage, apps-development

I am working on sharepoint 2013 apps and the content that I am adding is getting added below the master page UI, instead of getting added on the page, I mean it is not getting added on that UI. I have applied custom master page of my host site to my sharepoint hosted app.

Comment: check your page content place holders. and master page content place holders

Comment: My code of the page is in ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderMain" and my custom master page too contains the same placeholder with the same id. But yet it is not working. We place the code for the page into the same id while working on site pages. I think it should work but still it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved just copied the code of ContentPlaceHolder in the section where the previous code was removed